# Select the bands which not start with 'B' using regex in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, regular-expression

The image has the band : ['B1', 'B2', ..., 'B11', 'NDVI', 'NDWI'].
The goal is to select the bands which not start with 'B' using **`regex`**. In another words, ['NDVI', NDWI'].
What I know is that using `image.select("B.*")` to select bands start with 'B'. But I do not know to reverse the selection.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this:

```
image.select('[^B].*')
```